# Guava EventBus - FIFO or LIFO?

Tags: java, guava

This is a very generic question on EventBus. 
Does the EventBus exhibit a FIFO or LIFO behavior? I am using the EventBus as a Java event "queuing" mechanism and seeing LIFO behavior when a single publisher publishes events to the EventBus faster than the Subscriber can handle.

Comment: Please be more detailed about the circumstances you're seeing.

Comment: These are the 3 components I have - simple event bus, a publisher which publishes the events that contain the current timestamp, and a subscriber. The publisher creates the event with the current timestamp, then posts it to the event bus and the subscriber event handler function just prints the timestamp of the event. What I see is that timestamps are being printed in the reverse order.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post a minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[EventBus doc](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) says that the messages will be sent to all handlers, but there is nothing about their order. So I would not bet that the specific order is preserved. Even if now order is preserved without explicit information in the documentation, this may change in the future, so you shouldn't rely on these suspicions.

In particular, if you use an asynchronous implementation, then surely you don't have warranty of order.

If you need to send some messages and keep their order, you can use other solutions which ordering guarantees like [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_guarantees).

Comment: @annadobrowolska - In context of this question I am trying to understand the differences in the event bus implementations using guava eventbus and kafka. Let me know if you have links/thoughts. Thanks

Comment: I checked the EventBus implementations basically. It looks like the events to MainThread is FIFO, but there is no warrant on background threads.